# How to execute chown command in MS Windows properly

Tags: bash, cygwin, chown

I need to execute this script `test.sh` in windows from **BATCH** file but it says that there is no commands like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
# -*- ENCODING: UTF-8 -*-
chown system /etc/ssh*
chown system /var/empty
```

> chown: cannot access `/etc/ssh*\r': No such file or directory chown:
>
> cannot access `/var/empty\r': No such file or directory

The `chown.exe` is in its native place so.. Any clue?

Comment: The `\r` in `/etc/ssh*\r` seem to indicate a problem with the lineendings. Store the script with "unix lineendings".

Comment: @LarsFischer Would u mind to explain, please? Thank you!

Comment: Different OS use different lineendings. Unix convention is `\n`. Under Windows the convention is `\r\n`. I assume that cygwin sees a line ending with `\r\n` saved with a windows editor. It split the lines only with `\n` thus the `\r` remains (a windows command com would split the lines at `\r\n`). A programming editor should offer the possibility to save the file in either convention and the Unix lineending convention will probably work with cygwin.

Comment: @Dimi To convert from Windows line end convention  to Unix one  `d2u test.sh` . d2u is part of dos2unix package